# How to display the total value of items in a shopping list ecommerce

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am trying to figure out how to display the sum of all the items' subtotal, tax, and grandtotal value in the shopping cart, I currently have it so that it displays subtotal, tax, and grandtotal of each item. Here is a link to the site:

http://pbcs.us/~falcantara/projects/sauce/checkout.php

```
    <div class="container">

            <?php 

            while ( $row = $result->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
                         // Do something with $row
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $price = $row['price'];
                    $description = $row['description'];
                    $cart = $row['cart'];
                    $sku = $row['sku'];
                    $img = $row['img'];
                    $taxRate = .07;
                    echo "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>";
                    echo "<h2>" . $title . "</h2>";
                    echo "<img src='$img'>"; 
                    echo "<p class='fit'>" . $description . "</p>"; 
                    echo "<p>" . "$" . $price . "</p>";
                    echo "<form method='get'>";
                    echo "<p>Qty:";
                    echo "<select name='qty'>";
                        for ($i=1; $i <= $cart; $i++) 
                            { 
                                echo "<option>" . $i . "</option>";
                            }            
                    echo "</select>";
                    echo "</p>";
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="sku" value="'.$sku.'">';
                    echo "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger' value='Remove from Cart' />";
                    echo "</form>";
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo "<p>Subtotal: $" . $subtotal = $i * $price . "</p>";
                    echo "<p>Tax: $" . $tax = intval($subtotal) * $taxRate . "</p>";
                    echo "<p>Grandtotal: $" . $grandtotal = (floatval($subtotal) + floatval($tax) . "</p>");
                    echo "</div>";

            }
                    echo "<div>";

                        function addition() { 
                           global $subtotal;
                           for ($i=0; $i < $subtotal; $i++) { 
                                echo $subtotal;
                            } 
                           echo $sub;
                        }
                        addition();

                    echo "</div>";

            ?>

               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array("subtotal"=>0,"tax"=>0...); // before the begining of while loop

$arr["subtotal"] += $subtotal; // before the figure bracket of while loop
$arr["tax"] += $tax;
```

and then use your array values for the output.

Comment: Where would I put in the output? Would I use a superglobal like ($globals[$arr]) = sum($arr);?